# Approval process change effect on old record

Tags: administration, approval-process

I have approval process and they are many records which are already using this approval process. I want to remove this approval process and use new one. What will happen to existing records?

Answer (score 0):

Following are the two scenarios/use cases that come to my mind :

1. ***You just want to in-activate the older Approval process***

In the scenario 1, you can go ahead and make your approval process inactive and create a new approval process. The older records which were in the approval process would just be there in the "ProcessInstance" object. If needed, you can delete these records from "ProcessInstance" as well.

2. ***You want to delete the older Approval process***

In the scenario 2, following is what documentation says

```
Before you delete an approval process:
 a. Make sure it’s inactive.
 b. Delete pending approval requests that are associated with it, and remove them from 
    the Recycle Bin.
```

Reference :
https://help.salesforce.com/articleViewid=sf.approvals_considerations_manage.htm&type=5